# How to use validation rules in vue js 2 classic ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2

```
<ckeditor
              :editor="editor"
              :config="editorConfig"
              class="form-control form-urcv"
              rows="6"
              name="career summary"
              v-validate="'required'"
              :class="errors.has('career summary') ? 'is-invalid': ''"
              v-model="career.summary"
            ></ckeditor>
            <span
              v-show="errors.has('career summary')"
              class="invalid-feedback"
            >{{ errors.first('career summary') }}</span>
```

I was trying out ckeditor5 in vue.js, and I came across a problem of not being able to set it's height manually, avobe is my code please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have way to change color of editor, but if only need to show the validation message, you can use the following:

```
customValidateEditorData() {
    if (!this.career.summary || this.career.summary === "") {
        const error = {
            field: "career summary", //name of ckeditor
            msg: "the career summary is required.",
            scope: "save-post-form", //data-vv-scope of form
        };
        this.$validator.errors.add(error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
},
```

And don't forget to create the validator for page:

```
$_veeValidate: {
    validator: 'new',
},
```